# Listing category

Tags: categories, list

This is the code I'm using for listing categories:

```
<?php 
     $this_category = get_queried_object();
     $args = array(
                    'orderby' => 'id',
                    'show_count' => '0',
                    'child_of' => $this_category->term_id,
                    'use_desc_for_title' => '0',
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'hide_empty' => '0',
                    'child_of' => $this_category->term_id
      );     
      wp_list_categories($args); 
?>
```

If I enter to some category it's listing subcategories, then if I enter to subcategories i want to stay subcategories listed like when im in previous category.

Is there a chance to do this?

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Comment: `- category`
`-- subcategory`
`---- sub-subcategory`

If I'm on "category" It's listing "subcategory", but when enter to "subcategory" I don't want to list "sub-subcategory" I want to list "subcategory"

Answer (score 0):

If you know the depth that you want you can [add a depth parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) to `$args`

```
 $args = array(
                'orderby' => 'id',
                'show_count' => '0',
                'child_of' => $this_category->term_id,
                'use_desc_for_title' => '0',
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'hide_empty' => '0',
                'child_of' => $this_category->term_id,
                'depth' => 2
  );     
  wp_list_categories($args);
```

Experiment with that number if it isn't what you want.

This does not get you "all but the last level" functionality though. It gets you some set number of categories deep. If you want "all but the last level", I think you will probably have to build a custom Walker.